# Show that if $I<J <R $ and $R/I \cong \mathbf {Z} $, then $R/J $ is a finite ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> If $I$ and $J $ are ideals in $R$, $I$ is a proper subring of $J$, and $ R/I \cong \mathbf {Z} $, then $R/J $ is finite.

I know that if $R/J $ is not finite, it must be countable and so there must exist a bijection between it and $R/I$. Not sure how to show that this will imply $I = J $ or another contradiction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In your title you say that $I\ne J$.

The ideals of $R/I$ correspond to the ideals of $R$ containing $I$:
so $J/I$ is an ideal of $R/I\cong\Bbb Z$. It is a nonzero ideal so
maps to $n\Bbb Z$ for some $n>0$ under the isomorphism $R/I\to\Bbb Z$.
Then $R/J\cong (R/I)/(J/I)\cong\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$; this is finite.

Answer (score 1):

$J/I$ is a non-zero ideal of $R/I$.  By the isomorphism of the hypothesis, it corresponds to a non-zero ideal $n\mathbf Z$ of $\mathbf Z$, and by the *Third isomorphism theorem*, we have
$$ R/J\simeq (R/I)\bigm/(J/I)\simeq\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z, $$
which is finite.